# Series for handling calls

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm trying to calculate how many agents I need to reserve to handle calls.
This is the problem:

I receive 1 call per second, each call duration is ~20 seconds.
How many agents I need to handle 10,000 calls before the calls start queuing/caller needs to wait.
Example:

```
Time: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
      1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
```

For the first 20 seconds I have 20 agents which is fine, in second 21 a new call arrive but first call is disconnected:

```
Time: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
      0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 20 20 20 20
```

Is the top number of agents 20 ?
If I have 2 calls per second with a call duration of 20 seconds do I need 40 agents?

Comment: I think you can use ErlangC formula for that